# How do I receive a PyQt signal from another object when it is instantiated elsewhere?

Tags: python, pyqt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building a system to connect Arduino-based sensors to a RPi via Bluetooth LE, and display the info (temperature and battery life) on a GUI.  I have two main classes in my program, one that manages the GUI, and one that manages the BLE connection(`class HubSensor`).  A `HubSensor` object takes the MAC address for each sensor and is supposed to emit a signal with an attached tuple that contains the temp sensed, battery life, and an index integer to let the main program know which sensor it is.  `HubSensor` gets it's information once per second, and should be sending out the signal every time. (There is input validation already built but it's not relevant to my question.)  Most of this is working fine so far.

My problem is I can't figure out how to create a slot to receive the signal so it can update the display (and later keep a log in a CSV file).  I'm using the BluePy library to manage the BLE connection, which for me has it's own additional challenges.

So, this is how my program works (I think).  Each thread (since I have multiple sensors) creates a `HubSensor` object.  When the object makes the BLE connection, it then creates a `MyDelegate` object (subclassed from BluePy's `DefaultDelegate`.  Inside the `MyDelegate` object, the Qt Signal is emitted.  I need access to that signal outside of all of those classes and since I don't know the name of the `MyDelegate` object created, I don't know how to get to it.

I've tried having each of the above mentioned classes inherit each others' characteristics, but I'm not sure I did it right.

From trailerTempDisplay.py

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from HubSensor import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from bluepy.btle import *

from datetime import datetime


# mac addresses for the sensors.  later, this will need a function to allow new devices to connect
bt_addrs = ['c1:49:02:59:ae:50', 'f3:ad:ed:46:ea:16']

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, macAddress, ind):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.macAddress = macAddress
        self.ind = ind

    @pyqtSlot()
    #this is where each sensor exists.  each object is created and runs here
    def run(self):
        self.sensor = HubSensor(self.macAddress, self.ind)
        self.sensor.notified.connect(self.updateValues())

#close button
def buttonClicked():
    app.closeAllWindows()

window = uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui")
window.pushButton.clicked.connect(buttonClicked)


def updateValues(self):
    print("value updated")       # debugging


window.show()
window.threadpool = QThreadPool()
index = 0
for addr in bt_addrs:
    worker = Worker(addr, index)
    index += 1
    window.threadpool.start(worker)
app.exec()
```

From HubSensor.py

```py
from bluepy.btle import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal


class MyDelegate(DefaultDelegate, QObject):
    def __init__(self, index):
        DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.index = index

    # class variable for the notified signal
    notified = pyqtSignal(tuple)

    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        # exception handling prevents bad data from being passed.  cHandle is not used but might be useful later
        try:

            # defining the sensorData tuple.  1, 2, and 3 are dummy values
            self.sensorData = (1, 2, 3)
            self.notified.emit(self.sensorData)  # this should emit a signal every time the function is called and send a tuple with temp, battery, and sensor index(id)

        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            pass


class HubSensor(MyDelegate):
    # constructor.  connects to device defined by mac address and position.
    # uuid is static and should not change

    def __init__(self, mac, index):
        self.index = index  # keeps track of sensor position
        self.mac = mac
        self.p = Peripheral(self.mac, 'random')  # adafruit feathers must be 'random' for some reason
        self.p.setDelegate(MyDelegate(self.index))
        self.p.writeCharacteristic(35, b'\x01\x00')  # writing these bits to handle '35' enables notifications
        while True:
            if self.p.waitForNotifications(1):
                # when a bluetooth notification is received, handleNotification is called
                continue
```

When I run the program, "value updated" is not displayed on the console.  It should pop up about twice per second and just repeat.  Later, I will add in the part that turns the values passed into the GUI display.

Let me apologize in advance because I am still very much a beginner.  I think I've included all the relevant parts of my code, but I don't know for sure.  Also, I'm pretty sure my terminology in some spots is incorrect, so I hope you all can decipher what I actually mean.  Thank you in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: deleted the unneccessary stuff and put dummy values in for the sensorData tuple

Comment: Have you read the link? I think not, I want all the necessary code (eliminating the irrelevant) to reproduce your problem, and the code you provide is not enough.

Comment: apologies, I hope this edit will provide everything.

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is confusing, for example that HubSensor is a delegate whose attribute is a Peripheral and that Peripheral has another delegate, among other problems.

So instead of relying on your code, I created the PeripheralManager class that will notify the information received by the assigned peripheral through a signal. In the case of the infinite loop, it will be handled in a thread using threading.Thread.

```py
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
from bluepy.btle import DefaultDelegate, Peripheral, BTLEDisconnectError


class PeripheralManager(QtCore.QObject, DefaultDelegate):
    notified = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bytes)

    def __init__(self, peripheral, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._peripheral = peripheral
        self.peripheral.setDelegate(self)
        self.peripheral.writeCharacteristic(35, b"\x01\x00")
        threading.Thread(target=self._manage_notifications, daemon=True).start()

    @property
    def peripheral(self):
        return self._peripheral

    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        self.notified.emit(self.data)

    def _manage_notifications(self):
        while self.peripheral.waitForNotifications(1):
            continue


def buttonClicked():
    QtWidgets.QApplication.closeAllWindows()


def updateValues(values):
    print("value updated", values)


def main(args):

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(args)

    bt_addrs = ["c1:49:02:59:ae:50", "f3:ad:ed:46:ea:16"]

    managers = []

    for addr in bt_addrs:
        try:
            p = Peripheral(addr, "random")
        except BTLEDisconnectError as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            manager = PeripheralManager(p)
            manager.notified.connect(updateValues)
            managers.append(manager)

    window = uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui")
    window.pushButton.clicked.connect(buttonClicked)
    window.show()

    ret = app.exec_()

    return ret


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```